# typo3 captcha error

Tags: php, class, typo3, typo3-tca

Since a few days the captcha image doesn't show up anymore.

I when i try to reach the captcha.php the file gives me an error:

Fatal error: Class 't3lib_div' not found in /typo3conf/localconf.php on line 10

When I lookup the localconf.php file, the first 20 lines look like this:

```
<?php
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['sitename'] = 'New TYPO3 site';
    // Default password is "joh316" :
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['installToolPassword'] = 'bacb98acf97e0b6112b1d1b650b84971';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList'] = 'tsconfig_help,context_help,extra_page_cm_options,impexp,sys_note,tstemplate,tstemplate_ceditor,tstemplate_info,tstemplate_objbrowser,tstemplate_analyzer,func_wizards,wizard_crpages,wizard_sortpages,lowlevel,install,belog,beuser,aboutmodules,setup,taskcenter,info_pagetsconfig,viewpage,rtehtmlarea,css_styled_content,t3skin';
$typo_db_extTableDef_script = 'extTables.php';

// MAX FILE SIZE
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['maxFileSize'] = '100000';
t3lib_div::loadTCA('tt_content');
// This changes the upload limit for image elements
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['image']['config']['max_size'] = 100000;

// This changes the upload limit for media elements
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['media']['config']['max_size'] = 100000;

// This changes the upload limit for multimedia elements
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['multimedia']['config']['max_size'] = 100000;
```

Does anybody has an idea why I get this error?

Comment: Why do you have TCA settings in the localconf.php?

Answer (score 1):

The best would be that this settings below would be in ext_tables.php file of some extension.

But if you don't have any special ext for that then you can put that into `typo3conf/extTables.php` file. After that the error about `t3lib_div` not found should be gone.

```
// MAX FILE SIZE
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['maxFileSize'] = '100000';
t3lib_div::loadTCA('tt_content');
// This changes the upload limit for image elements
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['image']['config']['max_size'] = 100000;

// This changes the upload limit for media elements
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['media']['config']['max_size'] = 100000;

// This changes the upload limit for multimedia elements
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['multimedia']['config']['max_size'] = 100000;
```